# Import only part of a PDF file's page

Tags: pdf, import

Is it possible to only import part of a pdf file?
For example if I want to import lines 20 - 25 from page X from a pdf file, is this possible?

I am familiar with importing whole documents, or pages using \includepdf, but is this import of sections possible?

Moreover, would this result in a figure, or can it be inserted into "regular" text?

Comment: Have you tried `\includegraphics` options `page=...` and `viewport=...` yet?

Comment: includepdf has  the option  `pages=20-25`, and includegraphics has `page=20`.

Comment: Oh lines, not pages ;-). I completly misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't import a part of a PDF page as if it were text of your *.tex file, unless you just copy the text out of the PDF and paste it into your *.tex file as a quotation.

Either produce a picture (jpg, png, by taking a screenshot e.g.) and include this as it is (`\includegraphics`) or within an figure, or copy the text out of the PDF and paste it.

Using the viewport option of the graphics bundle isn't as easy as making a screenshot of the PDF.

Comment: Note that if your PDF content is vector-based, you'll be losing quality by taking a screenshot (which is rasterized). But if you "includegraphics" the PDF with cropping, the full PDF content is still present in your output file, increasing file size and possibly including information you don't want present. It's possible, though not trivial, to "truly crop" your PDF file: set the MediaBox by using Inkscape, for example, then "print to PDF" or use a tool like pdftocairo to drop all content outside the MediaBox.

Comment: @Keks With the Gv Postscript/PDF viewer, lower left and upper right corners of the viewport can easily be determined using the mouse pointer (cross hair).